# Multi-processing on Large Image Dataset in Python

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning

I have a very large image dataset (>50G, single images in a folder) for training, to make loading of images more efficient, I firstly load parts of the images onto RAM and then send small batches to GPU for training.

I want to further speed up the data preparation process ***before*** feeding the images to the GPU and was thinking about multi-processing. But I'm not sure how should I do it, any ideas?

Comment: How about multiple processes loading images into a [collections.deque](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) and a single process pulling from the deque and feeding the gpu?   https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#module-queue??

Comment: [Consumer/Producer Queues in Python - youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8moSZM8GnIk)

Comment: I just watched and practiced [Thinking about Concurrency, Raymond Hettinger](https://youtu.be/Bv25Dwe84g0) - it is worthwhile and should get you started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For speed I would advise to used HDF5 or LMDB:**

I have successfully used  [ml-pyxis](https://github.com/vicolab/ml-pyxis) for creating deep learning datasets using LMDBs.

It allows to create binary blobs (LMDB) and they can be read quite fast.
The link above comes with some simple examples on how to create and read the data. Including python generators/ iteratos

**For multi-processing:**

I personally work with Keras, and by using a python generator it is possible train with mutiple-processing for data using the fit_generator method.

```
fit_generator(self, generator, samples_per_epoch,
              nb_epoch, verbose=1, callbacks=[],
              validation_data=None, nb_val_samples=None,
              class_weight={}, max_q_size=10, nb_worker=1,
              pickle_safe=False)
```

Fits the model on data generated batch-by-batch by a Python generator. The generator is run in parallel to the model, for efficiency. For instance, this allows you to do real-time data augmentation on images on CPU in parallel to training your model on GPU. You can find the [source code here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/models.py#L817) , and the [documentation here](https://keras.io/models/model/#methods).

Comment: thanks for the reply. I'm also using fit_generator in Keras by feeding a data_generator. I find that changing the number of works doesn't make a difference at all...

Comment: @GoC 1 . Are you reading from files or from a binary blob  or are you reading images independently? 2. Are you feeding it as generator or data iterator ? I found that it worked fine for me when I was working with LMDBs.and with data generators.
3. Can you check the the time that is taking to read each batch on your process ? A simple time print inside you generator would help a lot.

Comment: @GoC. If yopu please reply the comment we can try to fix your problem.

Comment: I'm reading single images in one folder and using a data generator. I'll try using LMDB tomorrow and let you know, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: btw, is using LMDB significantly faster than using HDF5 when it comes to read large image data?

Comment: Yes. Binarys blobs like LMDB and HDF5 are much faster for reading.
 One because you loose the overhead of opening many files, two because the data location is stored in look up tables.
My suggestion for speeding up. When creating a dataset, shuffle the data before enrolling it to the dataset. This way you can use a sequential reader ( python generator). This would avoid you doing seek comands with your hardrive. These is the kind of solution used in Caffe and Digits.

Comment: If you are using a data iterator instead of generator it is much easier to have  locking threads .

@GoC another thing to consider, If you are doing heavy data augmentation (Computanially expensive), do it before, create the lmdb and then just feed the lmdbs/hdf5s to the fitter.

It also seems your question is not related to multiprocessing as `fit_generator` is a working piece of code that you can use replicate. your question seems to be moving towards ideal data management for deep learning. If so you should ask a new question  and please vote for the most appropriate answer for this.

Comment: As an examples your same question as been answered by the creator of Keras himself, with the same solution pointed here. https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/107

Comment: so generally it goes like this: first create a LMDB database and load images in folder to the database (chunk by chunk, when processing large data) and then using a data generator to read batches from database for training. I'll try it today

Comment: The ML-pyxis has examples of adding pictures to the dataset. As well as how to read batches of **sequential data** with a generator. But please don't make another question in comments,  as this would not be easy for other users to find. If you have further questions start a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know whether you prefer tensorflow/keras/torch/caffe whatever.

Multiprocessing is simply [**Using Multiple GPUs**](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/wiki/Using-Multiple-GPUs)

Basically you are trying to leverage more hardware by delegating or spawning one child process for every GPU and let them do their magic. The example above is for **Logistic Regression**.

Of course you would be more keen on looking into Convnets - 
This [**LSU Material**](http://www.hpc.lsu.edu/training/weekly-materials/2016-Fall/machine_learning_qb2_fall_2016.pdf) (Pgs 48-52[Slides 11-14]) builds some intuition

Keras is yet to officially provide support but you can ["proceed at your own risk"](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/pull/3582)

For multiprocessing, tensorflow is a better way to go about this (my opinion)
In fact they have some good **[documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/deep_cnn/index.html#training-a-model-using-multiple-gpu-cards)** on it too

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I think you may misunderstood my point, I just want to further speed up the data preparation process ***before*** feeding the images to the GPU.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by data preparation? Can you list the steps, be a little specific?